# Facebook Custom Conversions

Tags: facebook

I am looking to set up a custom conversion based on an "inventory_type" parameter sent from a third party website via my pixel. I have the custom conversion set up and running however it is for the entire website and I would like it just for my one ad campaign.

Also if I go to events manager and look at events it is saying that my "inventory_type" parameter has been removed. Any advice on how to break out the inventory type for a specific ad set?